# .wrapper not sorted correctly in filter edit popup

Tags: bug, api, api-v2.2, documentation

When editing the filter, e.g. on [this API documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids), all types are sorted alphabetically *except* for `.wrapper` which is always shown below `answer`, instead of above it (or at the end):

[image]

Obviously, this is not a big deal, but sorting everything alphabetically except for a single item is rather strange.